# Duplicate queries while removing multiple rows in one transaction in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm working with EF 6 and have the repository class such this:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public EfRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    ....
    public void Delete(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        // skip checks
        using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entities);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

In my controller I have repository instance `IRepository<Connection> _repository` than binded with Autofac to `EfRepository` class.

Then I remove multiple items (and everything works fine!):

```
IEnumerable<Connection> connections = // get some connections;
_repository.Delete(connections); // everything fine - records was removed
```

But when I open my site with installed [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com) it shows me duplicate sql-query warning:
[image: MiniProfiler warning]

My question is why I use transactions but still has duplicate sql warning?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are not deleting duplicate `connections`?

Answer (score 2):

This is because Entity Framework currently sends one query per item to be deleted. It does not batch them all into one query. So MiniProfiler is correctly reporting on what is happening - duplicate delete queries (with exception of the param value) are being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

What is your transaction.Commit() doing? Maybe you can add the code of this method to your question.

I am also deleting entites from my database but more like this:

```
public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (Context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DBSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            DBSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }
```

I think there are no differences between Remove and RemoveRange, but maybe you should check the state first?